# RandomForest Package Error in R: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r

I am attempting to create a Random Forest multi-class classifier. However, when I execute my code I get the following error on the call to RandomForest:

Error in results$training_classes :
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
Calls: randomForest ... eval -> model.frame -> model.frame.default -> eval -> eval
Execution halted

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
library(randomForest);
library(tm)
training_classes <- readLines("incidents_training_classes.txt",)
training_data <- readLines("incidents_training_words.txt")
doc.vec <- VectorSource(training_data)
doc.corpus <- Corpus(doc.vec)
summary(doc.corpus)
doc.corpus <- tm_map(doc.corpus, removeNumbers)
doc.corpus <- tm_map(doc.corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
DTM <- DocumentTermMatrix(doc.corpus, control=list(weighting=weightTfIdf,minWordLength=3))
DTM.common <- removeSparseTerms(DTM,.99)
# Convert DTM to a data frame
capture.output(DTM.dataframe <- as.data.frame(inspect(DTM.common))) -> .null
class.dataframe <- as.data.frame(training_classes, stringsAsFactors=TRUE) 
# Merge predictor variables and class labels
results <- cbind(DTM.dataframe,class.dataframe)
forest.rf <- randomForest( results$training_classes ~ .,importance=TRUE, data = results, ntree = 500);
```

The results data frame has the expected dimensions. I have poured over Google without any luck.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's rarely the case that an R `formula` (properly used) will have an "$" in it. What does `str(results)` show?

Comment: Here is the top of my structure call:`The metadata consists of 2 tag-value pairs and a data frame
Available tags are:
  create_date creator
Available variables in the data frame are:
  MetaID
'data.frame':   8271 obs. of  813 variables:
 $ able            : num  0 0 0.0171 0 0 ...
 $ accept          : num  0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ access          : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ accessing       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ account         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...`

Comment: Here is the bottom of the str() call: `$ yes             : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ yesterday       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ yet             : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ training_classes: Factor w/ 8 levels "B","C","D","G",..: 8 7 8 7 2 5 7 8 7 2 ...`

Comment: Appears to me that the 'results' object is something that is more complex than a dataframe. It is not appropriate as an argument for the randomForest data argument.

Comment: The output to is.data.frame(result) is: [TRUE].  I have not worked with Document Term Matrices prior. I usually scrub the data with sed/awk, etc. then read the text in as a table. In this case I am using a DTM. The DTM cannot contain the class labels to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

If you are specifying data = results, you dont need the $ sign. try:

```css
fmla <- as.formula(training_classes ~.)
results$training_classes <- as.factor(results$training_classes)

forest.rf <- randomForest(fmla,importance=TRUE, data = results, ntree = 500);
```

Should solve the problem instantly.

Also the independent variables should not contain any NAs. Please also share output of "str(results)". The factor variables being used in the forest should not have more than 32 classes, please keep that in mind.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but I get the following with your suggestion: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'else' not found
Calls: randomForest ... randomForest.formula -> model.frame -> model.frame.default -> eval -> eval
Execution halted`

Comment: The results of the str(results) are above in another comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try using only column names of the data.frame in formula, like `training_classes ~ .`. Check that column names are set properly with colnames(results). Alternatively, you can try `x=, y=` arguments instead of formula, see `?randomForest`.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback but I get the following with your suggestion: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'else' not found
Calls: randomForest ... randomForest.formula -> model.frame -> model.frame.default -> eval -> eval
Execution halted`

Comment: Could you post output of `head(results)` and your new `randomForest` call?

Comment: Hi. There are 813 variables, so posting the complete output of head() is not possible. Here is the bottom of the output showing the training_classes feature:  `yesterday yet training_classes
1         0   0                W
2         0   0                P
3         0   0                W
4         0   0                P
5         0   0                C
6         0   0                H`  Here is my randomForest call:  myforest.rf <- randomForest( training_classes ~ . , importance=TRUE, data = results, ntree = 500);  And, the error:  Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'else' not found